# SQL Query: Select most recent entry for each distinct field value?

Tags: sql

i have this table POSITION:

```
CREATE TABLE `position` (
  `idposition` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `latitude` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `longitude` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `timestamp` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `fk_email` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
```

with this population:

```
idposition  latitude    longitude   timestamp              fk_email
        1   39.49333    -0.33667    2010-12-10 17:15:39     david@test.es
         4  39.47333    -0.36167    2010-12-11 09:58:47     ronald@test.es
         5  39.50333    -0.34267    2010-12-10 21:11:10     david@test.es
        10  39.44333    -0.41667    2010-12-12 18:17:26     fanny@test.es
        11  39.45199    -0.31967    2010-12-12 21:01:18     victor@test.es
        12  39.52133    -0.36167    2010-12-12 17:43:11     carlos@test.es
        13  39.43199    -0.31967    2010-12-14 15:45:25     victor@test.es
        14  39.41199    -0.34567    2010-12-14 20:46:09     victor@test.es
        15  39.43433    -0.41667    2010-12-14 17:29:39     maria@test.es
        16  39.44133    -0.42667    2010-12-12 19:17:33     maria@test.es
        17  39.50333    -0.35667    2010-12-13 16:36:22     angel@test.es
        196     39.46454    -0.38978    0000-00-00 00:00:00     fanny@test.es
        271     33.63883    -0.45024    2010-12-17 11:36:45     fanny@test.es
        273     39.46680    -0.39452    2010-12-20 00:00:00     fanny@test.es
        441     39.44133    -0.41467    2010-12-15 17:45:13     carlos@test.es
        5326    39.47316    -0.38351    2011-01-18 18:09:56     pablo@upv.es
```

ok, i want to make  SQL Query, that returns to me THE LAST (NEWEST) POSITION OF EACH FK_EMAIL, i mean, for each `fk_email`, the position with the last (newest) `timestamp`, only one position (te last) for each email.

it is possible to do it? can someone help me with the query? is too munch hard for me

Comment: What database? What version??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT  
      p.idposition, 
      p.atitude, 
      p.longitude, 
      p.timestamp, 
      p.fk_email

FROM  
      position p 
      INNER JOIN (select 
              fk_email,
              max(timestamp) timestamp
                 FROM    POSITION 
                 GROUP BY  fk_email) lastPos 
      ON p.fk_email = lastPos.fk_email and p.timeStamp = lastpos.timestamp
```

The one potential problem with this is that if the same timestamp is recorded for the same fk_email you will get both results. If there was a unique constraint on the combination of these two columns you won't have to worry about that though.

**update**
From the comments

> but one question more, the only
>   possibility to be returned two rows
>   per email is to have the seame
>   timestamp in two rows for the same
>   email? how can i evade that

As I said before adding a unique constraint on the two fields so it doesn't happen is the easiest. But lets assume you can't do that and lets also assume that the timestamp is the same. you'll need to pick an *arbitrary* row as "the correct one".

Assuming that IdPosition is unique you could do this

```
SELECT 
     p.idposition, 
      p.atitude, 
      p.longitude, 
      p.timestamp, 
      p.fk_email
  FROM 
   position p
    INNER JOIN (SELECT  
                    max(p.idposition) idposition
              FROM  
                    position p 
                    INNER JOIN (select 
                            fk_email,
                            max(timestamp) timestamp
                               FROM    POSITION 
                               GROUP BY  fk_email) lastPos 
                    ON p.fk_email = lastPos.fk_email and p.timeStamp = lastpos.timestamp
              GROUP BY 
                     fk_email) lastpos
              on p.idposition = lastpos.idposition
```

Comment: it works on 99% of the cases, but i dont know why, it returns 2011-01-18 18:23:58  pablo@upv.es.............. when it have to return 2011-01-18 18:24:20  pablo@upv.es ----------------------> maybe it's because it fails when between positions exists a differente of less than a minute?

Comment: @AndroidUser99 That's weird I can't explain that. I'm doubtful of this but you try ordering by the timestamp descending in the lastPos query and see if that helps

Comment: but one question more, the only possibility to be returned two rows per email is to have the seame timestamp in two rows for the same email? how can i evade that?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
select * from
(select idposition, latitude, longitude, timestamp, fk_email, row_number() over(partition by fk_email order by timestamp desc) as rownumber
from position
) derived
where rownumber = 1
```

Comment: +1 Will work in SQL Server 2005/08 or Oracle. Don't know what other DB's support this

Comment: I assume that it will work in DB2 as it supports row_number() over (partition by)... don't see why it wouldn't also support an order by clause as well

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT idposition, atitude, longitude, timestamp, fk_email 
FROM   position 

GROUP BY fk_email HAVING MAX( timestamp )
```

Comment: #1630 - FUNCTION pervasive_locations.MAX does not exist. Check the 'Function Name Parsing and Resolution' section in the Reference Manual

Comment: Sorry - remove space after MAX

Comment: it works now, nice!!! existes the possibility to get two rows for a simple email? or it's impossible?

Comment: if you want to have 2 rows (1. with MAX( timestamp ) and 2. with previous timestamp ) you need to use Conrad Frix example and play with ORDER BY and LIMIT instead GROUP BY in INNERed table

Comment: I don't think this can give a correct result. Did you try it?